# How to create the __init__ function?

Tags: python

This is the instructions:

1.Define a class named Bag in a module named bag.py

2.Define an **init** method that has one parameter, an iterable of values that initalize the bag. Writing Bag() constructs an empty bag. Writing Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d']) construct a bag with one 'a', two 'b's, one 'c', and three 'd's. Objects in the Bag class should store only the dictionary specified above: it should not store/manipulate any other self variables

```
from collections import defaultdict
from goody import type_as_str
from test.test_string import Bag

class Bag:
    def __init__(self, i):
        if len(i) == 0:
            self.bag = []
        for x in i:
            self.bag.append(x)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    #driver tests
    import driver
    driver.default_file_name = 'bsc1.txt'
#     driver.default_show_exception= True
#     driver.default_show_exception_message= True
#     driver.default_show_traceback= True
    driver.driver()
```

This is the Error I got:

```
  7 # Test init, repr, and str
  8 *Error: b = Bag() raised exception TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'
  9 *Error: repr(b) in ['Bag()','Bag([])'] raised exception NameError: name 'b' is not defined
 10 *Error: str(b) raised exception NameError: name 'b' is not defined
 11 *Error: b = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d']) raised exception AttributeError: 'Bag' object has no attribute 'bag'
 12 *Error: all((repr(b).count('\''+v+'\'')==c for v,c in dict(a=1,b=2,c=1,d=3).items())) raised exception NameError: name 'b' is not defined
 13 *Error: all((v+'['+str(c)+']' in str(b) for v,c in dict(a=1,b=2,c=1,d=3).items())) raised exception NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

The input is:

```
# Test init, repr, and str
c-->b = Bag()
e-->repr(b) in ['Bag()','Bag([])']-->True
e-->str(b)-->Bag()
c-->b = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])
e-->all((repr(b).count('\''+v+'\'')==c for v,c in dict(a=1,b=2,c=1,d=3).items()))-->True
e-->all((v+'['+str(c)+']' in str(b) for v,c in dict(a=1,b=2,c=1,d=3).items()))-->True
```

I have no idea how to make the **init** function. since the first input calls b = Bag(), whcih will always raise Error: b = Bag() raised exception TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your init method is expecting the argument i to be initialize,
And another problem of your code is self.bag will never initialize to a list if len(i) is not zero, you can,t append to bag if its not define as list before hand.
Code below should fit what you want

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self, i=None):
        self.bag = []
        if i == None:
            pass # i is None, do nothing after create empty bag
        elif type(i)==list:
            self.bag.extend(i) # append whole list i into bag with extend method
        else:
            self.bag.append(i) # append single item i into bag 

# example
Emptybag = Bag()
Bag1 = Bag('item1') # Initialize with 1 item
Bag2 = Bag(['item1', 'item2']) # initialize with list of items
```

Answer (score 0):

The first raised exception:

Your `c-->b = Bag()` call expects an argument passed to Bag. For example `Bag(['f', 'o', 'o'])`

The second raised exception:

If you actually pass an argument through the Bag constructor the length will be greater than 0 and bag will never be *created* so you can't append to it. I am not sure what you are trying to do but maybe `self.bag = []` regardless of the length of i?

Comment: I am just not sure how to make it work. Since c-->b = Bag()  will always cause an Error if there is a parameter 'i' in the __init__ function. But the instruction asked me to create __init__ function with that parameter 'i'.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't fully understand what you are asking. Can you try changing  `def __init__(self, i):` to `def __init__(self, i = [ ]):`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like things may be simpler if you use the built-in [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class, which is in the `collections` module. From the docs:

```
>>> c = Counter()                           # a new, empty counter
>>> c = Counter('gallahad')                 # a new counter from an iterable
>>> c = Counter({'red': 4, 'blue': 2})      # a new counter from a mapping
>>> c = Counter(cats=4, dogs=8)             # a new counter from keyword args
```